# iOS Layout Constraints

Tags: layout, uiview, constraints, ios-autolayout

I’m configuring the layout for the UIView in the photo (photo in the link because I don’t have the points to upload it) and I’m having trouble configuring the constraints of the marked elements, which are the constraints for the two lines of buttons, the label that is between them and the label that is on the middle of the large image. The other elements are working correctly.  I’ve tried different things but still don’t get it right. I’ll appreciate if you could help me with which are the correct constraints I have to add.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6v1fsik9duvn0d7/Photo%20Apr%2023%2C%208%2042%2021%20AM.jpg?dl=0

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the buttons inside a view and add the constraints to the view and the buttons. It is working correctly now